# Custom InfoWindow for particular markers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm working on cab booking app where I use different type of markers(one for passenger and many for the cabs ) for the passenger marker I don't need a custom InfoWindow , but for the cabs'( where I show different information about them that can possibaly change) I do,therefore I've customed an InfoWindow one using a resource layout file (info_window.xml), but whatever I've tried (even using hideInfoWindow(); ) I couldn't hide the passenger's InfoWindow, also whenever I try to set Text to an InfoWindow TextView the app cruches ,If what I'm trying to  is possible then what I'm doing wrong ? If it is not, is there an other way to show information without using InfoWindows , something similar to this perhaps !
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVYjF.png) knowing that the InfoWindow have been converted to Bitmap I tried also to use Simple information balloon annotation for Android MapView as in this link https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons but it's deprecated ,What should I use instead !!
Ps:I need to have a clickable button on it.

this is **info_window.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvLatitude"
        android:text="Latitude"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
         />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvLongitude"
        android:text="Longitude"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and those are parts from **MapActivity.java**

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
GoogleMap map;
static Double latt, lngg;
private String[] perms = {"android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.INTERNET"};
HashMap<Integer, Marker> markerMap = new HashMap<Integer, Marker>();
Marker marker;

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(broadcastReceiver == null){
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                getJSON();
                lngg= intent.getDoubleExtra("longitude",-1);
                latt= intent.getDoubleExtra("latitude",-1);

                Marker m =map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(latt,lngg))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon2))
                        .title("I'm a passenger"));
                     m.hideInfoWindow();
              //  goToLocationZoom(latt, lngg , 15) ;


            }
        };
    }
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("location_update"));


}


class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
    String JSON_STRING;
    String json_url ;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        json_url="http://frequentative-hicko.000webhostapp.com/FetchLocAndId.php";
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(json_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder= new StringBuilder();
            while( (JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ){

                stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING+"\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();




        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        TextView textView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
      //  textView.setText(response); //JSON Format

        // System.out.println("json_string="+json_string);
        if(response== null){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        }
        else {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");
                int i=0 ;
                int id,e;
                Double lt,lg;
                while (i<jsonArray.length()) {
                    JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    e=  jo.getInt("etat");

                    id= jo.getInt("driver_id");

                    lt=jo.getDouble("latitude");

                    lg= jo.getDouble("longitude");

                     if(e==0){
                         marker = markerMap.get(id);
                         if(marker != null){
                             marker.remove();
                             markerMap.remove(id);
                         }else
                         {
                             markerMap.remove(id);
                         }
                     }else{
 map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

                             // Use default InfoWindow frame
                             @Override
                             public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {


                       return null;
                             }

                             // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
                             @Override
                             public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

                                 // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                                 View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);

                                 // Getting the position from the marker
                                 TextView tvLatitude= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLatitude);
                                tvLatitude.setText("Latitude ");
                                 // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
                                 return v;

                             }
                         });
                         if (markerMap.containsKey(id)) {

                    // Update the location.
                    marker = markerMap.get(id);
                    marker.remove();
                    markerMap.remove(id); //added
                    MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions()
                            .title("route_direct").position(new LatLng(lt,lg)).visible(true);
                    marker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);
                    markerMap.put(id, marker);

                    } else {

                        MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions()
                                .title("route_direct").position(new     LatLng(lt, lg)).visible(true);

                        marker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);
                        markerMap.put(id, marker);

                    }}

                    i++;}


                    }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            AlertDialog.Builder nbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapActivity.this);
            nbuilder.setMessage("Erreur")
                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                    .create()
                    .show();
            }

        }

   }
   }
   }
```

this the error I got

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: androidloginandregistration.inducesmile.com.ataxiapp, PID: 7484
              java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at androidloginandregistration.inducesmile.com.ataxiapp.MapActivity$BackgroundTask$1.getInfoWindow(MapActivity.java:331)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$7.zzh(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzd$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.p.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:94)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.by.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:89)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.by.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:124)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:188)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.g.c(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:200)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.db.g(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:23225)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.dd.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:304)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:242)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.m.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:4070)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.af.c(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:611)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.df.onSingleTapConfirmed(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:236)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.gesture.g.onSingleTapConfirmed(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:189)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.gesture.i.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:132)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving the steps here

1. Inflate your view in `onCreate`

   ```
   public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements    OnMapReadyCallback {
    ... 
    View v;
    ...

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, 0);
       v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
   }
   ```
2. Remove your logic from **getInfoContents** and add in **getInfoWindow**

   ```
   map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

                        // Use default InfoWindow frame
                        @Override
                        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {

                            // Getting the position from the marker
                            TextView tvLatitude= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvLatitude);
                           tvLatitude.setText("Latitude ");
                            // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents

                         return v;
                        }

                        // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
                        @Override
                        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
                         if (marker != null && marker.isInfoWindowShown()){
                            marker.hideInfoWindow();
                         }
                         return null;
                       }
                    });
   ```

Comment: I've tried it now ,but the app crushed again

Comment: post crash log.

Comment: When I removed tvLatitude.setText("Latitude "); I could run the app but the infowindow is still showing on the passenger marker

Comment: see updated code. it should be view.find like `v.findViewById(R.id.tvLatitude)`

Comment: I can run the app but  I still can't hide the passenger's infowindow

Comment: Ps :I've edited the question